# How do I pass and manipulate the arguments of a matrix into the function using pointers?

Tags: c

i have managed to send the arguments using pointers and matrix size inside of main like so:

```
int main()
{

    swap(*(matrix+0)+1, 0, 1, *(matrix+3)+2, 3, 2);
}
```

my question really is, how do I swap out these two values of the matrix using the following function?

this is what I have so far in regards to the function:

```
void swap(float **a, int i, int j, float **b, int x, int y)
{

    float temp;
    temp = *(a+i)+j;
    *(a+i)+j = *(b+x)+y;
    *(b+x)+y = temp;
}
```

The errors are: incomaptible types when assigning to type 'float' from type 'float *',
and lvalue required as left operand of assignment.

Comment: Your program cannot compile. Please add a complete program with the definition of `matrix`.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] in a question like this, please read and edit your question to include more code.

Comment: Instead of implementing a swap function the way you have, use a generic pointer-based swap function, then wrap it in the matrix-element-swap function - this will make it easier for you to avoid your bug.

Comment: Note that, if this is ISO C (as opposed to ISO C++) you can simply declare a variable of type `float matrix[rows][cols];`, allocate it using `malloc(sizeof(float[rows][cols]))` (if it is not on the stack) and access it using `matrix[i][j]`, letting the compiler do the offset maths for you. In this case, though, it wouldn't be an array of pointers, but a single array of floats of size `rows * cols`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
temp = *(a+i)+j;
```

The left-hand side here is still a pointer-to-a-float. You have not fully dereferenced your double-pointer parameter `a`. It's the same as writing:

```
temp = a[i]+j
```

what you probably meant was:

```
temp = a[i][j]
```

---

but actually, you could write it this way:

```
void swap_floats(float* a, float* b)
{
    float temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void swap_matrix_elements(
    float** matrix_a, int row_a, int col_a,
    float** matrix_b, int row_b, int col_b)
{
    swap_floats( &(a[row_a][col_a]), &(b[row_b][col_b]) );
}
```